# Need help in regular expression, remove all characters anyway except letters/digits and remove dots except decimal dots

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote this to find and remove all characters except letters, spaces, digits, percents and dots.

```
Regex.Replace("some string", @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\ \%\.]", "");
```

In fact, this find all characters except letters/spaces/digits/percents/dots,
I want to change it as follows:

Finding all special characters anyway (except letters/spaces/digits/percents) and finding dot only when there are not numbers around it.

How can I do this?

Comment: What about `123.456.789` (two dots between digits)?

Comment: And what to do with `.6.7. Something`?

Comment: When  `123.456.789` I do not need find them.

Comment: When  `.6.7.` I need to find the dots in the right and in the left but not in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd remove the dot from your regex and have an additional regex applied on the string as follows:

```
(?<=\D)\.(?=\D)
```

which will delete the dot only if it doesn't have any digit to the either side of it.

If you want to delete 3. as well as the above:

```
(?<=\D)\.
```

If you want to delete .3 as well:

```
\.(?=\D)
```

If you want to delete all 1.3, 3., and .3, then apply both of the above, no need for the first one as it becomes redundant.

Explanation:

The `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` are lookbehind and lookahead respectively, meaning it checks it's there, but won't include it in the substitution.

The `\D` means it's not a digit. `\d` means it's a digit.

The `\.` means it's a dot, it has to be escaped because `.` in regex means any character.

Comment: Nice answer. I think it needs to be in the same regex, though, coupled with `|`. Otherwise, think of what happens with `1•.•2`: first, the `•`s get removed, and then the second regex sees `.` is surrounded by digits.

Comment: At the end I used with `[^a-zA-Z0-9\ \%\.]|(?<=\D)\.|\.(?=\D)`  Thank you

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
            string test = "abc. 1.2";
            string pattern = "([a-zA-Z])(\\.)";

            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern);
            string output = expr.Replace(test, "$1");​
```